# Capture last element either between or after / and before?

Tags: regex, splunk

Say I have the following urls:

```
https://test.com/welcome/
https://sub.test.com/home/edit
https://test.com/home/view?view=column
https://test.com/home/view/?view=list
```

I would like to capture the following result:

```
welcome
edit
view
view
```

Right now I have `(?:\/[^\/]+)+?\/(.*?)/{0,1}$`, `(?:\/[^\/]+)+?(?:.*\/)(.*?)\?{0,1}$`, and `(?:\/[^\/]+)+?(?:.*\/)(.*)/\?.*$` but they are complicated and I can't seem to combine them.

Comment: Try [`.*/([^/?#]+)(?:/?(?:[#?].*|$))`](https://regex101.com/r/PmwQtR/1)

Comment: What language are you trying to do this matching in? Does that language not include a proper URL parser?

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew That seems to have worked, that one looks way nicer than what I was working with! If you make it an answer I'll accept it

Comment: `.*\/([^\/?#]+)` might be shorter.

Comment: @esqew The regex provided by another user seems to be working great with Python, but the end goal was to use this in splunk

Comment: Yes, you may use `.*/(?<part>[^/?#]+)` in Splunk

Comment: @anubhava Wow that does seem to work fine! Regex101 looks weird because of the newlines, but that's not an issue

Comment: For regex101 use: `.*\/([^\/?#\n]+)` or https://regex101.com/r/zZPm8m/1

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In Splunk, you may use a regex to match all text till the last occurrence of `/` followed with any 1+ chars other than `/`, `?` or `#` and these 1+ chars can be captured with a named capturing group:

```
".*/(?<lasturlpart>[^/?#]+)"
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/EZiqbi/1). Note the `\n` or `(?:/?(?:[#?].*|$))` in [my top comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60551904/capture-last-element-either-between-or-after-and-before/60552265#comment107124572_60551904) are used in the demo to make sure the match does not overflow across lines since the input is a single multiline string in the demo, while you will be using the regex against standalone strings.

**Pattern details**

- `.*` - any 0 or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible
- `/` - a `/` char
- `(?<lasturlpart>[^/?#]+)` - Named capturing group matching 1 or more chars other than `/`, `?` and `#`.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the plain-vanilla regex:

```
(?<=[\/])[^\/?=]+(?=\/?$|\/?\?)
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/t3RcOo/3/)

The regex can be written in *free-spacing mode*<sup>1</sup> to make it self-documenting:

```
/ 
(?<=[\/])     # match '/' or '?' in positive lookbehind
[^\/?=]+       # match 1+ chars other than '/', '?' and '='
(?=            # begin a positive lookahead
  \/?$         # optionally map '/' then match end of line    
  |            # or
  \/?\?        # optionally match '/' then match '?'
)              # end positive lookahead
/x             # free-spacing mode
```

<sup>1. I don't know if Splunk supports free-spacing mode but that is of no matter as I am using it merely to show how the regex works.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

```
| makeresults
| eval _raw="https://test.com/welcome/
https://sub.test.com/home/edit
https://test.com/home/view?view=column
https://test.com/home/view/?view=list"
| makemv delim="
" _raw
| stats count by _raw
| rex "^.*\/(?<result>\w+)"
```

greedy matching is fine.

`\w` is `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

Answer (score 1):

Go simple - regular expressions are all well and good, but `split()` is much easier (and, very often, much faster):

```
index=ndx sourcetype=srctp url=*
| eval url=split(URL,"/")
| eval lastpart=mvindex(url,-1)
```

This splits the field `url` into a multivalue field using the forward slash ('`/`') as the delimiter

Then select the last entry using `mvindex` and the index of `-1`, which is always the last entry